# SwaggerGen Enum Generation Empty DataType

Tags: java, json, enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url <<local repo not posted here>>
        }
        maven {
            url <<second local repo not posted here>>
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.swagger:swagger-codegen:2.4.7")
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.8.RELEASE"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    maven {
        url <<local repo not posted here>>
    }
}


import io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator
import io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator

def swaggerInput = "${rootDir}/BundledExports/API/POMOrchestrator.v1-Bundled.json"
// def swaggerInput = "${rootDir}/API/POMOrchestrator.v1.json"
def templatedir = "${rootDir}/templates".toString()
def swaggerOutputDir = file('application/')


task generateApi {
    inputs.file(swaggerInput)
    outputs.dir(swaggerOutputDir)
    doLast {
        def config = new CodegenConfigurator()
        config.setInputSpec(swaggerInput)
        config.setOutputDir(swaggerOutputDir.path)
        config.setIgnoreFileOverride(swaggerOutputDir.path)
        config.setLang('spring')
        config.setAdditionalProperties([
                'modelPackage'   : 'com.party.onboarding.models',
                'modelNamePrefix': 'Party',
                'dateLibrary'    : 'java8',
                'templateDir'    : templatedir,
                'interfaceOnly'  : 'true'   // Generating the Controller API interface and the models only

        ])
        config.setImportMappings([
                'hello': 'com.onbording.model.Hello'
        ])
        new DefaultGenerator().opts(config.toClientOptInput()).generate()
    }
}

clean.doFirst {
    delete(swaggerOutputDir)
}

configurations {
    swagger
}

sourceSets {
    swagger {
        compileClasspath = configurations.swaggerCompile
        java {
            srcDir file("${project.buildDir.path}/swagger/src/main/java")
        }
    }
    main {
        compileClasspath += swagger.output
        runtimeClasspath += swagger.output
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += swagger.output
        runtimeClasspath += swagger.output
    }
}

compileSwaggerJava.dependsOn generateApi
classes.dependsOn swaggerClasses
compileJava.dependsOn compileSwaggerJava

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.8.RELEASE'

    swaggerVersion = '2.7.0'
    springCloudServicesVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.RC1'
    cucumberVersion = '2.3.1'

    jackson_version = '2.4.2'
    jersey_version = '1.18'
    jodatime_version = '2.3'
    junit_version = '4.8.1'
}

dependencies {
    swaggerCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion"
    swaggerCompile 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.16'
    swaggerCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    swaggerCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'
    swaggerCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

    compile sourceSets.swagger.output

    compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:$jersey_version"
    compile "com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:$jersey_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jackson_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jackson_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jackson_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.1.5"
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:$jodatime_version"
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-codegen:2.2.3'

    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    runtime 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    runtime 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'
    runtime 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}
```

Open to suggestions on how to make this better

Here is my enum mustache file

```
  /**
   * {{^description}}Gets or Sets {{{name}}}{{/description}}{{#description}}{{{description}}}{{/description}}
   */
  @Getter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public enum {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{classname}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} {
    {{#gson}}
        {{#allowableValues}}
            {{#enumVars}}
    @SerializedName({{#isInteger}}"{{/isInteger}}{{#isDouble}}"{{/isDouble}}{{#isLong}}"{{/isLong}}{{#isFloat}}"{{/isFloat}}{{{value}}}{{#isInteger}}"{{/isInteger}}{{#isDouble}}"{{/isDouble}}{{#isLong}}"{{/isLong}}{{#isFloat}}"{{/isFloat}})
    {{{name}}}({{{value}}}){{^-last}},
    {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}
            {{/enumVars}}
        {{/allowableValues}}
    {{/gson}}
    {{^gson}}
        {{#allowableValues}}
            {{#enumVars}}
    {{{name}}}({{{value}}}){{^-last}},
    {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}
            {{/enumVars}}
        {{/allowableValues}}
    {{/gson}}

    private {{{dataType}}} value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} fromValue({{{dataType}}} value) {
      for ({{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} b : {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      {{#isNullable}}return null;{{/isNullable}}{{^isNullable}}throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");{{/isNullable}}
    }
  }
```

And here is the enum outer mustache class

```
{{#jackson}}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
{{/jackson}}
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

/**
 * {{^description}}Gets or Sets {{{name}}}{{/description}}{{#description}}{{{description}}}{{/description}}
 */
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} {
  {{#gson}}
      {{#allowableValues}}
          {{#enumVars}}
              @SerializedName({{#isInteger}}"{{/isInteger}}{{#isDouble}}"{{/isDouble}}{{#isLong}}"{{/isLong}}{{#isFloat}}"{{/isFloat}}{{{value}}}{{#isInteger}}"{{/isInteger}}{{#isDouble}}"{{/isDouble}}{{#isLong}}"{{/isLong}}{{#isFloat}}"{{/isFloat}})
              {{{name}}}({{{value}}}){{^-last}},
              {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}
          {{/enumVars}}
      {{/allowableValues}}
  {{/gson}}
  {{^gson}}
      {{#allowableValues}}
          {{#enumVars}}
              {{{name}}}({{{value}}}){{^-last}},
              {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}
          {{/enumVars}}
      {{/allowableValues}}
  {{/gson}}

  private {{{dataType}}} value;

  @JsonCreator
  public static {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} fromValue({{{dataType}}} value) {
    for ({{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} b : {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}.values()) {
      if (b.value.equals(value)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    {{#isNullable}}return null;{{/isNullable}}{{^isNullable}}throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");{{/isNullable}}
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the very large json file

```
    "knowledgeLevelCode": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "EXTENSIVE",
            "GOOD",
            "LIMITED",
            "NONE",
            "DECLINED"
        ],
        "description": "Knowledge Level Code."
```

And here is the code

```
  @Getter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public enum KnowledgeLevelCodeEnum {
    EXTENSIVE("EXTENSIVE"),

    GOOD("GOOD"),

    LIMITED("LIMITED"),

    NONE("NONE"),

    DECLINED("DECLINED");

    private  value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static KnowledgeLevelCodeEnum fromValue( value) {
      for (KnowledgeLevelCodeEnum b : KnowledgeLevelCodeEnum.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
  }
```

Not sure what is causing this to miss the data type.

Interestingly if I use OpenApi the data type is put in however there is an issue with nested includes that causes it to make several actual types just plain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a ton of searching I found the answer.  Basically it is a case sensitivity issue with the data type.   Somewhere they changed datatype to dataType but the version I am using to generate needs it to be lower case t.  So changing to this works.

```
{{#jackson}}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
{{/jackson}}
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

/**
 * {{^description}}Gets or Sets {{{name}}}{{/description}}{{#description}}{{{description}}}{{/description}}
 */
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} {
  {{#gson}}
      {{#allowableValues}}
          {{#enumVars}}
              @SerializedName({{#isInteger}}"{{/isInteger}}{{#isDouble}}"{{/isDouble}}{{#isLong}}"{{/isLong}}{{#isFloat}}"{{/isFloat}}{{{value}}}{{#isInteger}}"{{/isInteger}}{{#isDouble}}"{{/isDouble}}{{#isLong}}"{{/isLong}}{{#isFloat}}"{{/isFloat}})
              {{{name}}}({{{value}}}){{^-last}},
              {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}
          {{/enumVars}}
      {{/allowableValues}}
  {{/gson}}
  {{^gson}}
      {{#allowableValues}}
          {{#enumVars}}
              {{{name}}}({{{value}}}){{^-last}},
              {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}
          {{/enumVars}}
      {{/allowableValues}}
  {{/gson}}

  private {{{datatype}}} value;

  @JsonCreator
  public static {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} fromValue({{{datatype}}} value) {
    for ({{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}} b : {{#datatypeWithEnum}}{{{.}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}{{^datatypeWithEnum}}{{{classname}}}{{/datatypeWithEnum}}.values()) {
      if (b.value.equals(value)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    {{#isNullable}}return null;{{/isNullable}}{{^isNullable}}throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");{{/isNullable}}
  }
}
```